# Manually installing packages under Linux Mint 12

Tags: packages, installing, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

I've used Kile 2.1 under Ubuntu. To manually install a package, I did the following:

1. Copy package into `gedit` and save as `packagename.sty`
2. Put package in same named folder
3. Copy folder to `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex`
4. Type in terminal

   `$sudo mktexlsr`

...and that is it!

Now I (try to) use Kile 2.1 under Linux Mint 12 and the described procedure doesn't make any result. I'm bit confused, because Ubuntu and Mint are very similar distros. What do I need to do for manually installing a package in Linux Mint 12?

Comment: You problem is not related to Kile. It is a distribution problem. Most likely you are using TexLive. If you installed TexLive from it's homepage it will have a package manager 'tlmgr' otherwise you can try to `sudo texhash`